# Why is AJAX settimeout not working?

Tags: ajax, settimeout

I'm going a little crazy trying to understand why this outputs the json data once and then not again as per timeout function. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myTimer =0;
function ajax_get_json(){
var results = document.getElementById("results");
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
hr.open("POST", "ballJson.php",true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
        results.innerHTML = "";
        for(var obj in data){
            results.innerHTML += data[obj]+"<br />";
        }
    }
}
hr.send(null);
results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
myTimer = setTimeout('ajax_get_json()',10000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want to use the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) function as [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) only executes one time.

It is also much preferred to use `setTimeout(function () { ajax_get_json(); }, 10000)` or `setTimeout(ajax_get_json, 10000)` instead of using a string that is evaluated as the function callback.

Also note that the ajax requests may complete at any time, so it won't exactly be once every 10 seconds using `setInterval`.  You could also call `setTimout` in the `onreadystatechange` callback to chain the calls.

Comment: thanks, i'm not i follow why you rec setInterval and then all your examples use setTimeout?

Comment: @Gamemorize depends on what you want to do; I've described the two use cases and given you the two options, so it's up to you to choose which is best